# Using a trigger to update a specific value in one table based on a specific value of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

As the title says, I'm trying to update a *specific* row and column in one table, based on what a *specific* column in another table in another table is updated to. I have not been able to find anything on stack overflow specific to what I'm trying to do. So far, it's either updating one table based on the same table, or making an update based on whether the column changed (not looking for a specific value).

That said, I have so far pieced together the following code from my research on stack overflow:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trUpdateTaskToComplete on [DBName].[dbo].[Projects]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [DBName].[dbo].[TaskTracker]
    SET Complete=1
    FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Projects] t
    INNER JOIN inserted i on t.id = i.id
    AND i.Status='Complete'
END
```

This does 90% of what I need it to do, with the exception that it updates ALL the rows on the TaskTracker table that is associated with the project ID. How could I get it to only set Complete=1 on the rows where the Task (a column from TaskTracker) has the value of "ProjectIsComplete"? I tried something like this:

```
    UPDATE [DBName].[dbo].[TaskTracker]
    SET Complete=1
    WHERE Task = "ProjectIsComplete"
    FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Projects] t
    INNER JOIN inserted i on t.id = i.id
    AND i.Status='Complete'
```

but it seems that SQL Server is not about that life. What can I do to make my trigger work? Note: I only what the field set to complete for rows that have the Task value of "ProjectIsComplete" AND is still for the related ID. Thank you for any advice that can be offered!

Comment: Hi there, please note you can't use double quotes to signify a string in SQL Server.

Comment: I would suggest setting 2 temp tables to test your update first - then build this into the trigger

Comment: Move your where clause to the right spot. You have it in the middle. It goes AFTER the joins. And you should include the table reference and use single quotes.

Comment: Is that the only way to match the task? Is there no way of joining TaskTracker to Projects?

Comment: The double quotes were an accident; I meant to use single quotes.

Sean Lange, thank you so much! I moved my where clause to the end and everything worked out. Thanks, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Sean Lange** for the answer. The correct code is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trUpdateTaskToComplete on [DBName].[dbo].[Projects]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [DBName].[dbo].[TaskTracker]
    SET Complete=1
    FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Projects] t
    INNER JOIN inserted i on t.id = i.id
    AND i.Status='Complete'
    WHERE Task = 'Complete'
END
```